# How to handle csrf in spring boot production ready projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I am quite new to spring boot, And i was asked to implement post microservice endpoint to expose to other system to post some data in db(which I have handled through java code)

And I am planning to add basic auth with some client certificates (for eg: Tls).
Here the question is when I am trying to test the above Post api through postman csrf is enabled in spring boot automatically and it is blocking. Then I have added csrf.disable() in my config method and it works. But in production ready code we cannot disable using the above method I guess I think we have to handle bit different with it. Should i have to allow domain specific?? If yes how to achieve it?? Please let me know.

Comment: Are you planning to use this API from a website? Or, this is just for backend to Backend call?

Comment: Backend call it is